# Close a thread against a mysql database in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, resource-management

What is the proper way of closing a tread after running a query against a MySql database from a windows form in C#?

Is a simple open close enough like this?

```
conn.Open();

//querycode

conn.Close():
```

Comment: What do you mean by "close a tread"? Do you mean you want to make sure that the connection is closed after making a SQL call?

Comment: the problem im getting is that when i use the tool iv created m somtimes getting the "Too many connections" error, my mysql database is set ut with max_connections 100. and when i run a simple conn.Close(); after each query it does not seem to close the connection to the db. it dont releases the MySql treads before i restart the SW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
} // conn is automatically closed and disposed at the end of the using block
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes that use resources that you need to clean up afterwards usually implement the *IDisposable* interface.  This means it provides a function called Dispose() that can be used to free resources.

For disposable objects, you can use the *using* statement:

```
using ( SomeDisposableClass c = new SomeDisposableClass() ) {

    // ... your code here

} // c.Dispose() automatically called here, freeing up resources
```

If the class is properly coded, it should free any resources -- be it a database connection, an opened file handle, etc -- in its Dispose() function.

This means that the MySQL probably disconnects from the database in Dispose(), so you probably don't need to explicitly call c.Close() -- but always check the documentation to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

it is okay the way you are doing it, you can also wrap connection object into `using` block like this:

```
using (var con = new MySqlConnection(/*connection string*/))
{
    con.Open();
    //do stuff
    // con.Close(); //don't need this it will be closed automatically* 
}
```

(*[see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376068/does-end-using-close-an-open-sql-connection))

Comment: con.Close(); is redundant here.

Comment: for me it dont seem redundant because my app seems ot build more and more treads as im browing the MySql db from my tool.

Answer (score 0):

No, the code in your question is not good enough.  If your query throws an exception you won't Close() it in a timely manner and it will be left hanging until the garbage collector notices it.

You need to enclose the object in a `using` block as shown by others or at a bare minimum encase it in a try/finally structure.