# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: sql, timeout, connection, using, application-pool

I am fairly new in asp.net development, so you can say that I have developed a poorly coded application that is giving me this error.

**Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.**

I tried searching on google and found that it happens because of unclosed connections in the application pool so I carefully examined my application and inserted using keyword for all Sqlconnections but still I am having this problem, here is some sample code from my application. All Sqlconnections are enclosed in using statement like this.

```
    using (Connection = new SqlConnection(CIPConnection))
    {
        string ReturnValue = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader Reader;
            Connection.Open();
            string CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE NAME = @NAME AND PASSWORD = @PASSWORD";
            Command = new SqlCommand(CommandText, Connection);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", UserName);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", Password);
            Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
            Reader.Read();
            if (Reader.HasRows)
            {
                Session["ID"] = Reader["ID"];
                Session["NAME"] = Reader["NAME"];
                Session["DEPARTMENT"] = Reader["DEPARTMENT"];

                switch (Reader["DEPARTMENT"].ToString())
                {
                    case "Admin":
                        ReturnValue = "Admin";
                        break;
                    case "Editing":
                        ReturnValue = "Editing";
                        break;
                    case "Sales and Support":
                        ReturnValue = "Sales and Support";
                        break;
                    case "Writing":
                        ReturnValue = "Writing";
                        break;
                    default:
                        ReturnValue = "Sorry";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Response.Write(exp.Message.ToString());
        }
        return ReturnValue;
    }
```

Now my question is do I need to close Connection even in using statement block ? what will be the best way to close connection ? (putting it in finally block ? with every try statement ?) should I also use using statement with SqlReader and SqlCommand ? Please tell me the best way to get rid of unused connections so I can solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is related to the `SqlDataReader` object, which is not closed.  Try a `using` block:

```
using (var Reader = Command.ExecuteReader())
{
```

As a sidenote, the `Read` function returns false if no rows were found.  So you could shorten this:

```
Reader.Read();
if (Reader.HasRows)
{
```

to:

```
if (Reader.Read())
{
```

Answer (score 0):

No, when it exists the using block, it will Dispose, which will Close and return it to the pool. The problem lies elsewhere, or you missed one.

[Does End Using close an open SQL Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376068/does-end-using-close-an-open-sql-connection)