# Why is my ELSE statement being skipped?

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to use an IF/ELSE statement to query my MySQL database, but can't seem to figure out why the ELSE statement is being ignored by VB.  Here's the code - any help would be appreciated:

```
dbConn = New MySqlConnection("Server=" & FormLogin.ComboBoxServerIP.SelectedItem & ";Port=3306;Uid=qwertyuiop;Password=lkjhgfdsa;Database=zxcvbnm")
    Dim account As Boolean = True
    If dbConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        dbConn.Close()
    End If
    dbConn.Open()
    Dim dbQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE accountNumber = '" & TextBoxSearch.Text & "';"
    Dim dbData As MySqlDataReader
    Dim dbAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbCmd As New MySqlCommand
    dbCmd.CommandText = dbQuery
    dbCmd.Connection = dbConn
    dbAdapter.SelectCommand = dbCmd
    dbData = dbCmd.ExecuteReader
    While dbData.Read()
        If dbData.HasRows() = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Customer Account Found!")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No Customer Records Found!  Please try again!")
            dbData.Close()
        End If
    End While
```

My intent is to replace the messagebox in the "IF" clause with the code that will populate my form with the data from the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are already reading it:

```
While dbData.Read()
  If dbData.HasRows() = True Then
    MessageBox.Show("Customer Account Found!")
  Else
    MessageBox.Show("No Customer Records Found!  Please try again!")
    dbData.Close()
  End If
End While
```

If your reader has no records, the whole While loop will be skipped.

Try it the other way around:

```
If dbData.HasRows Then
  While dbData.Read()
    'looping through records here
  End While
Else
  MessageBox.Show("No Customer Records Found!  Please try again!")
End If
```

And also the obligatory note: Don't keep your connections open and alive.  Use the `Using End Using` bracket to automatically close your disposable objects.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The suggestion worked like a charm - and thanks to you I've learned something new.  But how would I use the USING END USING bracket - in my situation - to automatically open and close the connection?

Comment: @KismetAgbasi See [Does End Using close an open SQL Connection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/376068/719186).  Also, learn to use parameters.  Your sql query is ripe for sql injection and parameters would help prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's skipping your else clause, but it could be evaluating your if condition differently that you expect.

Personally, I don't like comparing anything to True.  If you drop the `= true`, does it work?

Comment: Didn't get a chance to try your suggestion to drop the '= true'.  I tried another suggestion from LarsTech and it worked - but thanks anyway Beth, I really appreciate it.