# Setting a SQL Server database connection in 4.0 framework (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

Be easy on me I am a recent college grad working on my first industry project. I built the app using 2012 and had to build on 2010. i have a combobox set to get the values from a database I access through VPN. The server has many different databases on it and every time I set the connection in 2010 it never gives me the option to access the any of the databases.
Steps taken:
Restarted program.
Searched this site religiously.
Tried multiple different connections.

I know there are other ways to get data into a combobox but I was using the configuration wizard vs 2010 offers to set up my connection. This is where the two versions of vs differ for some reason. 2012 let me view all the databases on the server. 2010 did not it automatically put me on master which gives me no way to access another db.

Here is vs 2010
[image: This is all the connection shows me]

Comment: Please post your code - nobody here (that I know of) have crystal balls or can read minds :)

Comment: Please show your database connection. Where do you read it from?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Should we assume that "2010" and "2012" refer to versions of Visual Studio?

Comment: Please explain more.  What do you mean by set the connection?  Tried multiple different connections.  We need to know what you are actually doing.

Comment: Yes visual Studio and that's just it with 2012 i clicked the combobox to bind data items then selected new project data source. There was no code written

Comment: Give me just a sec to get what I can of the data conenction

Comment: One thing of note is that you should not be blocking on this because the latter half of the application depends on the combobox. Until you get a solution you should be able to put static values in to have a working combobox. You should only be blocking on parts where the database is critical. So for example in your data layer where you are currently trying to access the database just return your own datasets and then hook it up to the database when you get that working.

Comment: Try running the application in the debugger. is it failing when an attempt to open the database fails. At least in the debugger the real exception can be captured.

Comment: @Chris I have tested it with a static value to make sure it works now is getting the value form the database

Comment: @Vincent I can't post pictures till I have a rank 10

Comment: @CharmingInferno: My point was that if the latter half of your app is dependent on the combobox and not on the database then static values will allow you to develop the second half of the app. It may be that I misunderstood and the rest of the app is DB dependant too but I was just wanting to address your last line suggesting you were unable to continue development.

Comment: @Chris yes it is vague i will edit and yes the rest is done it's the values in the db that is all that is left.

Comment: Now you can post pics...

Comment: @Tim that's just it was using the wizard with vs 2010

Comment: Here is a good Q&A on populating a combobox in a Windows form.  I would recommend against relying on wizards until you know how to do it by hand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423911/how-to-populate-c-sharp-windows-forms-combobox

Comment: @DaveSwersky alright I will go do that now and thank you!

Comment: @DaveSwersky after looking at it the connection i have in 2012 says dbconnectionetc(setting) while 2010 says conenction.etc.master.dbo why the difference?

Comment: Try the code and update your question with specifics if you have a problem.

Comment: The page is bugging me not to continue in comments, so here is one more question to refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113931/c-sharp-populate-a-combobox-from-table-in-database