# Reading tables from SQL Server Express database

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-express

I am trying to read my tables that are contained within my database in SQL Server Express, but it keeps coming up empty. What is it that am doing wrong?

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";

    string query = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Updated but still empty:

```
  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con2.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

            SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr2.Read())
            {

                comboBox1.Items.Add((string)dr2[0]);

            }


        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }}
```

Latest Updated code. Think I figured it but still showing empty:

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con2.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ";
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

            SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr2.Read())
            {

                string Dtables = dr2.GetString(dr2.GetOrdinal("TABLE_NAME"));
                comboBox1.Items.Add(Dtables);

            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }}
```

Full class:

```
    namespace unique_database{ public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
        string query = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[" + textBox1.Text + "](" + "[Code] [varchar] (13) NOT NULL," +
       "[Description] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL," + "[NDC] [varchar] (50) NULL," +
        "[Supplier Code] [varchar] (38) NULL," + "[UOM] [varchar] (8) NULL," + "[Size] [varchar] (8) NULL,)";


        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True");
        string filepath = textBox2.Text; //"C:\\Users\\jdavis\\Desktop\\CRF_105402_New Port Maria Rx.csv";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath);
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] value = line.Split(',');
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow row;
        foreach (string dc in value)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc));
        }

        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            value = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            if (value.Length == dt.Columns.Count)
            {
                row = dt.NewRow();
                row.ItemArray = value;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock);
        bc.DestinationTableName = textBox1.Text;
        bc.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
        con.Open();
        bc.WriteToServer(dt);
        bc.Close();
        con.Close();

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv|XML files (*.xml)|*.xml";


        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.textBox2.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void FillCombo()
    {
        try
        {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con2.Open();
                string query = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ";
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

                SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr2.Read())
                {
                    int col = dr2.GetOrdinal("TABLE_NAME");
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(dr2[col].ToString());
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to read into something like a DataReader.  ExecuteNonQuery is for things like INSERT that don't return values/data.

Comment: updated the code but still empty @DonBoitnott

Comment: How hard could it be ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113931/c-sharp-populate-a-combobox-from-table-in-database

Comment: @Fourat that is not what am looking for.

Comment: @Fourat said table, not table values. I know how to do that already

Comment: @Jevon in case you didn't notice `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` is a table that contains data about tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first, don't use `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` to fill `comboBox1`.
use `YourForm.OnLoad` event, the form constructor, or click a button, but don't use `SelectedIndexChanged` to fill itself, because you're executing this procedure every time you select one item of `comboBox1`.

To get column index simply use: `dr2.GetOrdinal("TABLE_NAME");`

```
private void FillCombo()
{
    try 
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con2.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

            SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr2.Read())
            {
                int col = dr2.GetOrdinal("TABLE_NAME");
                comboBox1.Items.Add(dr2[col].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Still empty for some reason

Comment: have you any table in your database? how many results if you use the select statement in SSMS? have you opened the combobox?

Comment: delete the code of actual question and paste the whole class.

Comment: Yes I have opened the comboBox and yes I do have tables. 4 of them. I ran the `"SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES "` and the TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME and TABLE_TYPE comes up. Narrowing it down to this command" `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` displayed the table data alone so yeah tables are present

Comment: there is an error in this code, can you compile it w/o errors?

Comment: There are no errors or warnings. Just the comboBox values not working

Comment: @Jevon, there was an error, I correct it. Please, put a breakpoint in while (dr2.Read()) for example, and try to debug it. How many time while loop is executed?

Comment: No I saw that error that was just a misplaced bracket and semi colon. That's why am saying there wasn't an error. I'll see what comes up with breakpoint

Comment: where are you calling FillCombo(); ? Add it to Button1_Click event for example

Answer (score 0):

Use ExecuteReader() instead of ExecuteNonQuery().then Use SqlDataReader() for get result.

Comment: @Jevon this answer give you an idea of where to begin. Look for help on MSDN about ExecuteReader(), I'm sure you'll find some sample there.

Comment: Yeah I did all of that but still empty on my latest updated code @mcNets