# Correct Method for checking if an item has been disposed

Tags: .net, vb.net, garbage-collection, dispose

What is the correct syntax in VB .net for checking that an object has been disposed of?

In my case, the public-declared database connection (`dbLocal`) is disposed of by a USING block and calling the database connection again triggers an error.

I've tried implementing the `.IsDisposed` code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isdisposed%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) but the declaration requires a Get, which i'm not entirely sure how to add.

Once I can check it .isdisposed, what is the correct method to recreate the public object?

DB Declaration:

`Public dbLocal As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" & Replace(Application.StartupPath, "\", "\\") & "\\database.db;FailIfMissing=True")`

USING loop:

```
Using dbLocal

'Create Command & add parameters
Dim Typecmd As New SQLiteCommand(TypeSQLI, dbLocal)
    With Typecmd.Parameters.Add("@id", DbType.String, 50, "id")
        Typecmd.Parameters.Add("@description", DbType.String, 100, "description")
        Typecmd.Parameters.Add("@sex", DbType.Int16, 1, "sex")
        Typecmd.Parameters.Add("@master", DbType.String, 50, "master")
        Typecmd.Parameters.Add("@size_min", DbType.String, 2, "size_min")
        Typecmd.Parameters.Add("@size_max", DbType.String, 2, "size_max")
        Typecmd.Parameters.Add("@size_half", DbType.Int16, 1, "size_half")
        Typecmd.Parameters.Add("@lining", DbType.String, 2, "lining")
    End With

Dim adapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter()
adapter.InsertCommand = Typecmd

Try
    Dim iRowsInserted As Int32 = adapter.Update(typetable)

    'Output result
    LstProcessed.Items.Add(iRowsInserted & " records added.")
    LstProcessed.TopIndex = LstProcessed.Items.Count - 1

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Import error. " & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Check syntax of imported file (were there headers?).", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End Try

End Using
```

Ideally the 'IsDispose' function will check if the DB is closed before entering the USING loop.

I've added the IsDisposed declaration, as documented in the MSDN article, resulting in...

```
Public ReadOnly Property IsDisposed() As Boolean
    Get
        ???
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Post some code. What is `dbLocal`? `SqlConnection`?

Comment: There's no generic way to take a disposed object and be able to create a copy which is like the object was before it was disposed. It may have performed arbitrary amounts of clean-up which destroys data that it held when it was live. The whole point of the dispose pattern is that you call `Dispose` when *you* know that you no longer require this object. If you're hitting a situation where you have an object and are unsure if it's been disposed or not, you're using it wrong.

Comment: As I say above, it seems the database connection is being closed once VB completes the USING loop.

Basically as documented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376068/does-end-using-close-an-open-sql-connection)

Comment: If you place something in a `Using` statement, you're telling the system "when we exit this `Using` block, I no longer require access to this object". If that's not the case then *don't use a `using` statement*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to check for disposal of an object.

You should ideally wrap it in a Using block like this:

```
Using obj As New foo
    'use your object
End Using
```

Next time you use it wrap the code in another Using block.

I think your issue is not creating a **New** object at the start of your Using block. You probably want this:

```
Using dbLocal As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" & Replace(Application.StartupPath, "\", "\\") & "\\database.db;FailIfMissing=True")
    '...
End Using
```

Here the scope of `dbLocal` is only for the lifetime of the `Using` block. Currently you are using a global variable which is being disposed of at the `End Using` line.

Comment: Cheers. The obvious answer is usually the best one.

Answer (score 3):

While the OP's problem seems to be their use of a using statement without understanding its implications, readers may want a clear answer to the question actually posed by the title.

The answer is, sadly, one can only tell via try/catch and unfortunately the exception you must catch is resource dependent.  Personally I find this to be a failing of the IDisposable interface but what's done is done and as mentioned already, one can't know how long it would be true anyway.

Most disposed objects throw InvalidOperationException but this is only a convention.  Unless you have documentation for the object in question you can only be sure by deliberately disposing an instance and trying it to see what is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if one doesn't know whether an item is disposed, one doesn't know enough about its state to perform any operations that would depend upon its state.  Classes which contain notification methods should write them in such a way that they may be safely invoked in any state (an object should simply ignore notifications when it's in a state where it doesn't care about them).  In most cases where the pattern:

```
if (!thing.IsDisposed)
  thing.DoSomething();
```

would make sense, the pattern should be implemented *within* the class of `thing` itself [e.g. because `BeginInvoke` is often used to notify controls of a change to a property they might be monitoring, `Control` should (but doesn't) have a `TryBeginInvoke` method which would silently do nothing if a control isn't able to accept it].  Occasionally (as with `Control.BeginInvoke` one has to kludge around the absence of such a method, but generally the only time one wouldn't already know whether something had been disposed is if things can get disposed outside of one's control; in that situation, even if `IsDisposed` returns false, one may not know how long that would continue to be the case.